# How to integrate uglify-es in grunt?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, gruntjs, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I'm using `gruntjs` (which uses `uglifyjs`) to build my `Angularjs` app. But `uglifyjs` still does not support es6, so in corresponding GitHub issue i found [this](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/448#issuecomment-300274963). So now there is uglify-es, which seemingly supports es6. But I'm not sure how to integrate it with grunt. Now i have module `"grunt-contrib-uglify"`, which has a dependency `uglifyjs`, which is now used. How can i make grunt use `uglify-es` instead?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**2023 UPD: this answer may be outdated, according to some comments. Didn't have time to check**

I've achived this by installing the harmony branch of `grunt-contrib-uglify`, which supports es6:

```
npm install git://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify.git#harmony --save-dev
```

Comment: Is this still the way to use for es6. I tried installing the above module and got a Permission denied on /var/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-5257398a
npm ERR! /private/var/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-5257398a/.git

I changed the permission to 777 for /var/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/ but still end up with the error

Comment: @jitenshah, do you have an error when just installing grunt-contrib-uglify, not specific branch? npm install grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev

Comment: No. I was able to install it easily. Even though I was in # prompt --> I ran your command with sudo like : 
sudo npm install git://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify.git#harmony --save-dev

and I was able to get the work done.

Comment: This answer saved my day.

Comment: its locked and cant be installed

Answer (score 15):

The ECMAScript version has finally been released.
You can now get the same result with the official version (it's no longer needed to pick it from GitHub)

```
npm install grunt-contrib-uglify-es --save-dev
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-uglify-es

Comment: Thank you for sharing this :)

Comment: Though the accepted answer solves the problem, this is the better and stable one than the accepted one, possibly because it is the more up-to-date solution.

Comment: It's weird that it says 'This packed has been deprecated' but thx.

Comment: because it is deprecated, it doesnt work for me